# How can I add GFCI protection to these bathroom lights?

Tags: lighting, bathroom, gfci, recessed-lighting

[image: current setup. 1 goes to the square light, 2 is from the switch (I think), 3 goes to the circular light.]

I have two lights (well, the square one is also an exhaust fan) in my bathroom.

There is a blue box that I've opened up to connect these lights. I've labeled the three wires going into the box. 2 is from the switch (I think), 1 is going to the square light, and 3 is going to the circular light.

The circular light is wet rated, but I believe I should GFCI protect it to be safe. What is the easiest way to GFCI protect the circular light?

I was thinking I could install a blank face GFCI outlet in the blue box, something like this: https://a.co/d/6lIX8mj

For installing this, would I connect wire 2 into the input terminals of the GFCI and wires 1 and 3 to the load terminals?

Or is this not a sufficient way to GFCI protect the lights? enter image description here

Comment: GFCI protection will probably last longer if not in the bathroom.  A GFCI breaker in the panel will do the job just as well.

Comment: You could use a GFCI outlet and connect the fan to that and feed the lights in front of the CFGI.

Answer (score 5):

Lights, fans, heaters etc. in shower stalls or over tubs must be GFCI protected.

You cannot conceal a GFCI above a drop ceiling.

Your best bet is to find GFCI protected outlets which are already required in the bathroom and extend off them to power that light.

If the bathroom switches are in a multi-gang box that also has a receptacle in it, that could be pretty easy :)

You could also use a GFCI breaker on the entire circuit.

Comment: Go Harper, lets get to 300k

Comment: @Ruskes hopefully that'll be enough to reinstate Monica!

Answer (score 3):

Lights in a bath are usually not on a GFCI. If it opens you can be left in the dark. Only a fan in the shower ceiling is required to be on a GFCI. It's not likely that the humidity in a bath will carry a dangerous current to someone using the bathroom.

Putting a blankface GFCI in the ceiling box will make it very difficult to get the lights back on in the event it trips.